# View profile page PHP

Tags: php, html, css, user-profile

So I have a admin panel I am creating for testing purposes just for experience and I am trying to make it so when you are logged in ( Using PHP sessions ) you can click the button profile and it will take you to your profile and display your name , email , usergroup. All them i have in my database however i can't seem to display them..

Here is my code

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
    if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
        //check user exists
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT username, email, usergroup FROM members WHERE username='$username'");
        if (mysql_num_rows($check)===1) {
            $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
            $username = $get['username'];
            $email = $get['email'];    
            $usergroup = $get['usergroup'];
        } else {
            echo "<h2>User does not exist!</h2>";    
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    <body>
        <php? echo $username; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

So do you have any ideas?

Thanks ,

Also - I have define $username as a variable there but when i display it and load the page it just says Undefined variable: username in

Comment: MySQL is deprecated from PHP 5.5.x, use [MysSQLi Functions](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [MySQLi Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)

Comment: var_dump() yout $_GET see if you have 'username' in your get

Comment: Don't really get that ^ :} Sort of new , sorry.

Comment: Clue: `<php? echo $username; ?>`

Comment: @ilovecode Was thinking the same thing but figured that was just a typo in the question ... if that was in the real code I don't think he would even get the `undefined variable` error

Comment: But it raises a good question... @user3618613 what's the deal with `<php?`

Comment: Not too sure why it done that but in my real code its <?php echo $username; ?>

Comment: scope issue? Try declare $username before the if(isset()).

Comment: Nope that did not work :{

Comment: Beside my answer: You're not closing the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to determine where the actual error occurs. So let's have a look.

Let's start with your includes:

```
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
```

These are two unknown sources. So hard to say whether there is something wrong.

If you check for the username passed by URI:

```
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
```

This may cause an error (while it is unlikely that it invoces the error in your case), because if you pass a GET variable key without value (e.g. `index.php?foo` leads to `isset($_GET['foo']) == true`, while `!empty($_GET['foo']) == false`. So it's handy to use `!empty()` instead of `isset()` here.

Your check if username is alphanumeric:

```
if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
```

Since [`ctype_alnum()` "checks if all of the characters in the provided string [...] are alphanumeric"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php), the error may be cause by passing a username with non-alphanumeric characters.

You have no `else {}` definition for the alphanumeric check. Consider doing so, e.g. by adding

```
if(ctype_alumn(...)) {
    // ...
} else {
    echo "<h2>Alphanumeric username required!</h2>";
    exit();
}
```

Your MySQL fetch seems to be okay, otherwise your

```
echo "<h2>User does not exist!</h2>";   
exit();
```

would fetch it.

Finally, also consider adding the else case for your `isset($_GET['username'])` check, e.g. like this

```
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
    // ...
} else {
    echo "<h2>No username provided!</h2>";
    exit();
}
```

## Sidenote about `var_dump()` usage

@Andy commented the recommendation to use `var_dump()` to dump information about `$_GET['username']`. Here is an example:

```
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
    var_dump($_GET['username']);
    exit();
}
```

will print out something like

```
string(7) "Foo Bar"
```